# How do I dynamically discover packages from a partial namespace in perl?

Tags: perl, package, autodiscovery

I have a directory structure that looks like:

Foo::Bar::Baz::1
Foo::Bar::Baz::2 etc

Can I list the packages from something like:

`use Foo::Bar::Baz;`

Thanks!

Edit: Made it more clear what the modules are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, are you looking at random packages in random Perl code?

Or for Perl **modules**, e.g. "a/b/c/d1.pm" with module "a::b::c::d1"?

In either case, you can not use a single "use" statement to load them all.

What you need to do is to find all the appropriate files, using either `glob` or `File::Find`.

In the first case (modules), you can then load them either by `require`-ing each file, OR by converting filename into module name (`s#/#::#g; s#\.pm$##;`) and calling `use` on each module individually.

As far as actual packages nested in random Perl files, those packages can be:

- Listed by grepping each file (again, found via `glob` or `File::Find`) for `/^package (.*);/`
- Actually loaded by executing `require $file` for each file.

  In this case, please note that the package name for each of those packages in `a/b/c/1.pl` will **NOT** need to be related to "a::b::c" - e.g. they CAN be named by the file author "p1", "a::p1" or "a::b::c::p1_something".

Answer (score 7):

If you want to load all modules in your include path with a certain prefix (e.g. everything under `a::b::c`, you can use [Module::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~crenz/Module-Find/Find.pm).

For example:

```
use Module::Find 'useall';

my @loaded = useall 'Foo::Bar::Baz';  # loads everything under Foo::Bar::Baz
```

This depends on your `@INC` path being set up with the necessary directories, so do any required manipulation (e.g. with `use lib`) first.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a script such as a/b/c.pl won't have a namespace other than `main`.  Perhaps you are thinking of discovering *modules* with names such as a/b/c.pm (which is a bad name, since lower-cased package names are generally reserved for Perl internals).

However, given a directory path, you can look for *potential* Perl modules using [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;

my @modules;
sub wanted
{
    push @modules, $_ if m/\.pm$/
}
find(\&wanted, 'A/B');

print "possible modules found:\n";
print Dumper(\@modules)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but you can inspect the symbol table before and after loading the module and see what changed:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my %original = map { $_ => 1 } get_namespaces("::");
require Inline;
print "New namespaces since 'require Inline' call are:\n";
my @new_namespaces = sort grep !defined $original{$_}, get_namespaces("::");
foreach my $new_namespace (@new_namespaces) {
  print "\t$new_namespace\n";
}

sub get_namespaces {
  # recursively inspect symbol table for known namespaces
  my $pkg = shift;
  my @namespace = ();
  my %s = eval "%" . $pkg;
  foreach my $key (grep /::$/, keys %s) {
    next if $key eq "main::";
    push @namespace, "$pkg$key", get_namespaces("$pkg$key");
  }
  return @namespace;
}
```

---

```
New namespaces since 'require Inline' call are:
        ::AutoLoader::
        ::Config::
        ::Digest::
        ::Digest::MD5::
        ::Dos::
        ::EPOC::
        ::Exporter::
        ::Exporter::Heavy::
        ::File::
        ::File::Spec::
        ::File::Spec::Cygwin::
        ::File::Spec::Unix::
        ::File::Spec::Win32::
        ::Inline::Files::
        ::Inline::denter::
        ::Scalar::
        ::Scalar::Util::
        ::Socket::
        ::VMS::
        ::VMS::Filespec::
        ::XSLoader::
        ::vars::
        ::warnings::register::
```